# How do we ask questions regarding different faiths without being offensive?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I have multiple questions regarding other faiths I'm not fully familiar with. However I don't want to make it seem like I'm either poking at in disbelief/disgust in their doctrines or causing a situation of heated argument.

What are some specific steps we can follow in the spirit of Christianity in asking questions of faiths we are not familiar with?

Answer (score 5):

So long as the question pertains to Christianity in some way ("How exactly is Islam different from Christianity," for a top-of-the-head example), then it should be fine. If you think you're going to be offensive in asking a specific question, post it on the meta first and see how others react.

I believe it's nobody's position to judge you if you were associated with a faith other than Christianity anyways. Since the site is about Christianity and not specifically for Christians, we're always open to welcome questions from people form other faiths who simply want to learn more or get something clarified.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you could invite others to edit your question. Within the body of the question to help make it non-offensive.  Just a single line like "If this question is offensive in any way, please help me by editing it." would suffice.

That's the beauty of the SE sites is that others can edit your questions to help you refine them.